# Comparing subgroup to the overall group, using 3 different tests for nominal and ordinal data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a dataset, which has different categories, such as Females vs Males, Race, Ethnicity
I also have responses - nominal (yes/no) or ordinal (from 1 to 7).

I plan to use 3 tests:

Ordinal data

**- Mann-Whitney U test (for 2 groups)**

**- Kruskal-Wallis test (for > 2 groups)**

Categorical data

**- Chi-Squared test (for 2 or more groups)**

But I am not sure if these tests are appropriate to compare a subgroup (African Americans vs others etc), because it looks like it compares AA vs Whites, Males vs Females etc.

Appreciate any references.

Appreciate your help!